# No Result From Barcode Scanner

Tags: android, barcode, listactivity, zxing

I'm using ZXING IntentIntegrator in order to read a URL.
I managed to launch the barcode scanner using:

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(List8.this);
dialog = integrator.initiateScan();
```

The barcode scanner indicated that a URL has been found and redirects me back to my application where I retrieve the information using:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
     if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), contents, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // Handle successful scan
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // Handle cancel
            }
        }


      }
```

The problem is that even thought a URL has been found the requestCode is -1 and the intent has no data.

Does anyone have any idea what's the source of my problem?

P.S.

I tried implementing onActivityResultListener but got the following error:

```
The return type is incompatible with PreferenceManager.OnActivityResultListener.onActivityResult(int, int, 
     Intent)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you expect the resultCode to be not `-1`? The `resultCode` is used to determine the intention, the "why" you have called the activity for result. Nothing more, nothing less... I would just remove the `if (requestCode == 0)` as it isn't really important.

Comment: I was sure that -1 indicated a failure, my bad.

Comment: can you explain how your unrelated answer answers the question. i dont know why the asker tick the answer but i pray and hope there's some kind of trick

Comment: @Dagon the question is old and I somehow don't get what the OP really wants but thanks for being so rude to mark my answer as "unrelated". For obvious reasons the OP thought different back then. Anyway, if you have issues, just ask and tell me what the problem is and don't judge questions/answers that are 2 years old.

Comment: i'm so sorry. i don't really mean to be rude at all. perhaps because my english is a little poor.  would you mind to update the answer with the solution for "P.S" part?

Comment: @Dagon I would love to help but beside the error no details are mentioned, so I have no real clue how to help. If you have a similar issue, maybe you create a question and point me to it, so I can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you aren't looking at `resultCode`? The value of `RESULT_OK` is in fact -1 (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_OK).

If you are using the integration code, then `requestCode` will be `0xC0DE` actually. But, you don't need to bother with these details and getting them right if you just use `IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult()` from the project. See the javadoc which shows how to use this fully.